# Set the name of a Jquery selector as a string in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm quite a noob at Jquery but I'm trying to set a variable based on the name of a form element.

I.e. variable = "someForm" based on this example:

```
<form id="hello" name="someForm" >
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

I'm using the following code which doesn't seem to work:

```
var formName = 0;
$('input').parentsUntil('form', this).focus(function() {var formName = this.name;})
if (stTime == 0) { // This ensures someone cannot start a form multiple times
    var stTime = new Date();
    stDelay = stTime - loTime;
    alert(formName);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `focus` event will not bubble, see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html#t06

Couple of other issues:

1. The `formName` variable being assigned to inside the event handler isn't the same variable as the first line since you're re-declared it, it then exists only inside the scope of that event function.
2. [`parentsUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) will return all ancestors **until** the `form` element, not the element itself which is presumably what you want.

Your code is out of context so it's difficult to understand how `formName` and the timer variables should be used and where they should be declared, but this should work for the event:

```
$('form :input').focus(function() {
    formName = $(this).parents('form').attr('name');
});
```

`:input` is a jQuery selector that matches all `<input>` types, along with `<textarea>` and `<select>`

Answer (score 0):

The `focus` event will bubble, so you can just use:

```
$('form').focus(function() {
  formName = this.name;
});
```

But it'd be better to store your timer when it's submitted, for example:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  formName = this.name;
});
```

Also don't use `var` inside the event handler, as this will create a new, local variable, *not* set your `formName` variable declared above it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var formName = 0;
$('input').parentsUntil('form', this).focus(function() {var formName = this.name;})
```

This can't work. You are trying to assign to the formName variable defined in the first line, but you're redefining the variable in the second line. You are actually dealing with two different variables, one in the function scope and one in global scope.

**Solution:**

```
var formName = 0;
$('input').parentsUntil('form', this).focus(function() {formName = this.name;})
//                                                      --- no var here
```